# Incomplete emoji in the string java

Tags: java, unicode, xhtml, emoji

I have a string fetch from database having emoji's. If suppose someone try to put some incorrect emoji like `ud83d\ude00`. In this case the system cannot find the correct combination and then rest of the string is not displaced. If this kind of string is inserted I need to display as such. Can any one please help

Edit:-
I convert the string into UTF-8 format and then it worked, Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Wouldn't the priority be to validate the content before it is stored in the database? The alternative would be to make assumptions about content, e.g. a regex matching uxxxx\uxxxx and correcting it, but I think that will cause you other problems.

Comment: `\ud83d\ude00` is Unicode ['GRINNING FACE' (U+1F600)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f600/index.htm), so that seems ok.

Comment: \ud83d\ude00 is proper smiley, but the ud83d\ude00 is wrong. If some user enter it by mistake how will i restrict this

Comment: I need to print something like ? if not found. But in java how can I do it?

Comment: You can try some methods from org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils